# Project Structure in MVC design Pattern iOS

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, architecture, software-design

First of all i know MVC well and have been using it in project but when it comes to organizing classes and there role i am bit not sure of there proper implementation. Lets take a scenario to proceed with:

A sample which will display All Employee and Department. Data will be fetched from Web Services(Json) and will be stored as offline(Core Data).

So MVC pattern would be:

1. View will be my storyboard with Employee and Department UIViewController.
2. Controller will be EmployeeViewController.swift and DepartmentViewController.swift
3. Model will be Employee.swift and Department.swift

   ```
   class Employee: NSObject {
       var name: String?
   }

   class Department: NSObject {
       var departmentName: String?
   }
   ```

   4. ServiceManager which will make calls to the web service.
   5. ParseData which will parse the web service response and convert it into Employee and Department objects
   6. CoreDataManager is singleton class to manage CRUD operation on offline DB.

Here are series of question on the above scenario which i have:

1. Is my understanding correct? Is the structure which i am trying to build follows proper MVC?
2. How the controller will interact with these components (Service Manager, ParseData, CoreDataManager). Should there be another class which will facilitate the communication between controller and data management(if controller does this then it will a tightly-coupled structure and massive as well).
3. Should Model be having any code other then property and initialization method as most of the model which i have seen only have property declaration?
4. Should there be separate UIView classes instead of storyboard to create a proper MVC structure?

Comment: Hi Arun, your structure separation is correct when it comes to iOS development. The thing is that iOS is a bit quirky with how it understands MVC. I've personally written a more developed blog post on my website regarding how my thoughts on how iOS apps are (or should be) structured. Feel free to have a read if this subject interests you: https://epic-apps.uk/2015/04/19/ready-set-xcode/

Comment: Thanks Bravo and it clarifies my doubts to an extent. I would say its a nice blog.But can you elaborate more on 2 and 3 question above? If you have any sample kept around do share that as well.

Comment: Any class that is a `UIViewController` should be classified as a Controller.

Comment: I disagree, @ZGski. Would you perhaps explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct? Is the structure which i am trying to
>   build follows proper MVC?

First I will say that "proper" MVC will depend on who you're asking. Its origin is commonly attributed to [Trygve Reenskaug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trygve_Reenskaug) when he introduced this into Smalltalk in the 70's. However, his type of MVC was widely different from the bloated versions most commonly used today. The modern way of thinking about MVC is

- Model = mostly a dumb class which primarily encapsulates data
- View = whatever we present on the screen
- Controller = the big lump of code that does almost everything,
  sometimes offloaded by a manager class or two of some sort

Reenskaug, however, would have a model and a view and a controller for a button. For a label. For a field. I'm not saying that is what we should strive for, but there should be better ways to structure a project than using the **M**assive **V**iew**C**ontroller pattern (as it is jokingly referred to in the iOS community).

Luckily, there are.

[Uncle Bob](https://twitter.com/unclebobmartin?lang=en) is preaching [Clean Architecture](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html). There are several implementations of this, and various people have made their own implementations of this for iOS, like [VIPER](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/) and [Clean Swift](http://clean-swift.com).

> How the controller will interact with these components (Service
>   Manager, ParseData, CoreDataManager). Should there be another class
>   which will facilitate the communication between controller and data
>   management(if controller does this then it will a tightly-coupled
>   structure and massive as well).

Following the principles of Clean Architecture, you should encapsulate these functionalities into layers, in a way that enables you not just to split the code into multiple components, but also enables you to replace them with other components when that is needed. (But yes, at the very least avoid putting all of this in your controller!)

> Should Model be having any code other then property and initialization
>   method as most of the model which i have seen only have property
>   declaration?

Again, there is not a single answer here. Some proponents of "real" OOP will say that each object should be self-served (i.e. a model object should know how to persist itself), while others extract the knowledge of such operations into "managers". Putting code to persist an object into the object could mean littering persistence functionality into many objects, or require you to rely on subclassing or other solutions to avoid this coupling.

> Should there be separate UIView classes instead of storyboard to
>   create a proper MVC structure?

Storyboard or not does not determine whether you're using "proper" MVC. Also, what *kind* of class you're choosing (UIView or UIViewController) to represent the View is also not important. Your ViewController can be dumbed down to such a degree that it contains no logic (forwarding the logic that it DOES have to another class, i.e. the Presenter in VIPER).

I would recommend reading about the Clean Architecture and maybe watch a [video of Uncle Bob explaining it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_TH-Y78tt4), read other people's [reports on implementing it](https://medium.com/brigade-engineering/brigades-experience-using-an-mvc-alternative-36ef1601a41f#.n3c21s6r1), and then consider whether MVC is the correct pattern for your iOS project.

Comment: Nice answer. Great highlighting the massive view controller issue in iOS. Just wanted to add that container view controllers are a great way of encapsulating responsibility of portions of a UI to help avoid bloated controllers.

Comment: Thank you, @SandyChapman. I agree; container view controllers can help with the issue of bloated VCs as well.